Neovim: Any way to create a higher-level split?
Say I have a window with 3 stacked panes:
┌──────────────────┐
│                  │
│                  │
├──────────────────┤
│                  │
│                  │
├──────────────────┤
│                  │
│                  │
└──────────────────┘

Is there a command (or plugin?) to open a fourth pane that’s essentially a level above the split tree:
┌─────────┬────────┐
│         │        │
│         │        │
├─────────┤        │
│         │        │
│         │        │
├─────────┤        │
│         │        │
│         │        │
└─────────┴────────┘

